# I can import a namespace but can't use fully qualified class names

Tags: .net, vb.net, namespaces

I'm having an odd issue with a reference to an assembly

I have a VS2008 project which references an assembly with the RootNamespace `Business.CHHS`.  When I import the namespace, the contained classes are properly exposed

[image: Working]

However, if I instead use the fully qualified name, it can no longer find the referenced namespace or its types.

[image: NotWorking]

I've definitely put in the reference and built the solution (everything compiles in the first example).  When I'm typing the namespace into the imports statement, I get full intellisense support for CHHS, when i'm specifying the variable type, CHHS does not show up under the Business namespace.

**Q**: *What's going on here?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will happen anytime that you are attempting to use a namespace that also exists anywhere within the hierarchy of the currently scoped namespace.  Let me explain me with the following example:

Say you have the following code:

```vb
Namespace Company.Application
    Module Module1
        Sub Main()
            'Code Goes Here
        End Sub
    End Module
End Namespace

Namespace Company.Application
    Public Class ApplicationClass
    End Class
End Namespace

Namespace Company.Business
    Public Class BusinessClass
    End Class
End Namespace

Namespace Business
    Public Class RootLevelBusiness
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Now let's see what's exposed when we go to use the *`Business`* Namespace in our Module (we should expect to see the *`RootLevelBusiness`* class

[image: Business]

**But We Don't!!!**

That's because the code has worked it's way up the hierarchy of the current namespace and found a business class before getting to the root.  To help prove that, look what happens when we include *`Company`*:

[image: Company]

You'll see that *`Company`* is greyed out because it doesn't need it.  It would be running the same code with or without qualifying that it comes from Company, because we're already in the *`Company`*`.Application` namespace.

## Solution - Use `Global`

If you'd like to qualify classes inline, you need a way of telling the compiler to not look inside of your current namespace when resolving classes.  For this, use [**`Namespace Global`**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2011/09/27/announcement-namespace-global.aspx) which provides:

> a new way to “escape” your classes out of the project’s Root Namespace

[image: global]

Global tells the compiler to start from scratch, in which case we immediately find the Business namespace.

The reason you can add the class through the [**`Imports`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x.aspx) statement without using Global is because `Imports` is global by default.  Because you have to declare `Imports` before defining any `Namespaces`, the imports statement has no way to presume what the namespace will be in any subsequent block of code in the rest of the file because you can (although probably shouldn't) declare as many namespaces as you want within a single file.  For this reason, Imports will always start from the root of any namespace and work it's way down.